# Difference between 2 SQL queries from same table

Tags: sql

Table SECURITYGROUPSID:

```
GROUPNAME    |    SIDNAME    
--------------------------
Group 1           Apple
Group 1           Apples
Group 1           Applesauce
Group 1           Applesauces
Group 1           Appleton
Group 2           Apple
Group 2           Applesauce
Group 2           Appleton
```

I need the difference in SIDNAME values between Groups 1 and 2 for values like 'Apple%'. For example, if I perform the following 2 queries, I need the result query at the bottom.

```
SELECT SIDNAME FROM SECURITYGROUPSID WHERE GROUPNAME = 'Group 1' AND SIDNAME LIKE 'Apple%';
SELECT SIDNAME FROM SECURITYGROUPSID WHERE GROUPNAME = 'Group 2' AND SIDNAME LIKE 'Apple%';
```

The result query should be:
Apples
Applesauces

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `not exists()`

```
select o.sidname 
from securitygroupsid o
where o.groupname = 'Group 1' 
  and o.sidname like 'Apple%'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from securitygroupsid i
    where i.groupname = 'Group 2'
      and i.sidname = o.sidname
      )
```

or using `not in()`

```
select o.sidname 
from securitygroupsid o
where o.groupname = 'Group 1' 
  and o.sidname like 'Apple%'
  and o.sidname not in (
    select i.sidname
    from securitygroupsid i
    where i.groupname = 'Group 2'
      and i.sidname like 'Apple%'
      )
```

or `left join`

```
select o.sidname 
from securitygroupsid o
  left join securitygroupsid i
    on o.sidname = i.sidname
   and o.groupname = 'Group 1'
   and i.groupname = 'Group 2'
where o.sidname like 'Apple%'
  and i.sidname is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `except` (SqlServer) between your queries. (Or `MINUS` for Oracle)

```
SELECT SIDNAME FROM SECURITYGROUPSID WHERE GROUPNAME = 'Group 1' AND SIDNAME LIKE 'Apple%';
EXCEPT
SELECT SIDNAME FROM SECURITYGROUPSID WHERE GROUPNAME = 'Group 2' AND SIDNAME LIKE 'Apple%';
```

Comment: This is a good answer as well for the given example. Note that `except` will de-duplicate the results (with some overhead for the sort operation) where as the options in my answer would not. SQL Server has not implemented `except all` which would avoid the de-duplication and extra sort cost.

Comment: That is true, a Set will be returned.